# Customize how search results look in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

If anyone knows of a "built-in" way to "customize" how search results look in VS2015, please let me know. In the interim and in the answer below, I will offer a temporary substitute for those who may not already know this.

I have LONG path names and am tired of missing the "actual" search result unless I scroll right. With this fix below, you can customize your results so that, for example, only the file name shows and NOT the full path.

Comment: Please separate this into a question and an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of googling with no success, I found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/11/24/did-you-know-you-can-customize-how-search-results-are-displayed-in-the-find-results-window-363.aspx) article by Sara Ford (thanks Sara!) with a tidbit that evidently never made it into that book version, and I thought that it was worth sharing until there is a more "built-in" way to do it. It's pretty easy through RegEdit (do at your own risk though) and below is a quick summary. Maybe I'll write a free plugin to do this or continue to hope that MS incorporates it into the next release of VS. This worked like a charm for me!

*Hope this helps someone!  -- HB*

---

1. Go to HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\ **EnterYourVersionHere(e.g. 14.0)** \Find
2. Add a new string called: **Find result format** (keep spaces intact - it's weird)
3. Set value of new string to: **$f$e($l,$c):$t\r\n** 
   ... where

**$f** is the filename, **$e** is the extension, **$l** is the line, **$c** is the column and **$t** is the text on the line

Looks like this when done:

[image]

---

*Here's a full list of the items for your enjoyment. :)*

***File info***

- `$p` =path
- `$f` =filename
- `$v` =drive/unc share
- `$d` =dir
- `$n' =name
- `$e` =.ext

***Location info***

- `$l` =line
- `$c` =col
- `$x` =end col if on first line, else end of first line
- `$L` =span end line
- `$C` =span end col

***Text info***

- `$0` =matched text
- `$t` =text of first line
- `$s` =summary of hit
- `$T` =text of spanned lines

***Char info***

- `\n` =newline
- `\s` =space
- `\t` =tab
- `\\` =slash
- `\$` =$